# WordPress отказывается показывать карту для *НЕ* администраторов

Tags: wordpress, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста,такая дичь происходит.Если зайти на страницу администратором,то видно карту.Когда заходишь гостем\пользователем\кем-угодноНеадмином,то карта не грузится.Просто пустой div,сайт кинуть не могу,так как на локальном.Подключаю файл map.php через include строчки кода:

map.php

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(init);

function init(){     

    var myMap9;

    myMap9 = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 13,
        controls: []
    });


    //выше карта не трогать

    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [55.76, 37.64]
    }
});
    myMap9.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

  myMap9.events.add('click', function (e) {
    // Получение координат щелчка
    var coords = e.get('coords');
    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates([coords[0],coords[1]]);
});
}
</script>
<style>
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Подключается в файле тут:

```
<div><?php include('map.php'); ?></div>
```

UPD: Выдаёт блок как надо,просто нету визуализации карты.

```
                <div class="clear"></div>

            <div><script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(init);

function init(){     

    var myMap9;

    myMap9 = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 13,
        controls: []
    });


    //выше карта не трогать

    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [55.76, 37.64]
    }
});
    myMap9.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

  myMap9.events.add('click', function (e) {
    // Получение координат щелчка
    var coords = e.get('coords');
    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates([coords[0],coords[1]]);
});


}


</script>
<style>
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
<div id="map"></div></div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: Какую страницу возвращает сервер под клиентом в браузере?

Comment: Я добавил выше,в комментарии нельзя говорит столько писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег script предназначен для описания скриптов, может содержать ссылку на программу или ее текст на определенном языке.
Одновременно добавлять и то и другое нельзя.
Разделите код и загрузку апи на два тега script.

Comment: Понял,сейчас попробую.

Comment: Боже Вы волшебник!Спасибо большое Вам!